# How to get the number of parameters required to run a script?

Tags: python, subprocess, arguments, method-signature

I am developing a project in Python to automate tasks. Very often I have to run scripts from different programming languages (Python, Perl, Ruby, C...) directly in my project. For that, I use the `Popen` class from the `subprocess` module.

Example:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "/dir1/dir2/.../dirN/23841.py", "arg1 arg2 arg3"], stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

However, not all of these scripts require the same number of arguments (and type of argument) to run. I would therefore like to implement a function which takes as parameter the absolute path of a script (`/dir1/dir2/.../script.pl`), and which returns me the number of arguments required to run this script.

I looked at the `inspect` module and its signature method. It works very well to know the number of parameters required to execute a function:

```
import inspect

def test(p1, p2, p3):
    None

print(len(inspect.signature(test).parameters)) #3
```

However, here I would like to find a method that returns me the number of arguments required to run a script (Python, Perl, Ruby, C...).

Comment: In general this is not possible. Your best bet is to have metadata about the scripts (number or arguments, optional argument names etc.) stored in a separate place (a sqlite db, or a config file). A better option is to modify those scripts to have an option to tell you what the signature looks like in a standard format. Like some sort of `--help` option but machine-redable instead of human readable.

Comment: i think it's possible that you dont need to know that in advance.... for starters how do you know what the arguments should be for the script? whatever means you use to get those arguments should also be able to tell you how many there are right ?

Comment: Many Linux utilites have myriads of valid option and argument combinations. No chance to automatically check the count in advance.